# URL string construction for CMIS

Tags: url

I have in an configuration xml the following things

```
<host>http://alfresco-test:8180</host>
<properties>
<property>
  <name>cmis-endpoint</name>
  <value>alfesco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>webscript-rest-endpoint</name>
  <value>alfresco/s/api</value>
</property>
</properties>
```

I read these and construct like below.

```
cmisAtomPubUrl = URLEncoder.encode((this.host + "/" + this.cmisAccessPoint), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());


SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
Map<String, String> parametersMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
/*https://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.9.0/maven/apidocs/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/commons/SessionParameter.html*/
parametersMap.put(SessionParameter.USER, this.user);
parametersMap.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, this.password);
parametersMap.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, cmisAtomPubUrl);
parametersMap.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());

List<Repository> repositories = new ArrayList<Repository>();
repositories = sessionFactory.getRepositories(parametersMap);
```

I am getting an exception, like this.

```
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisConnectionException: Cannot access "http%3A%2F%2Falfresco-test%3A8180%2Falfesco%2Fapi%2F-default-%2Fpublic%2Fcmis%2Fversions%2F1.1%2Fatom": no protocol: http%3A%2F%2Falfresco-test%3A8180%2Falfesco%2Fapi%2F-default-%2Fpublic%2Fcmis%2Fversions%2F1.1%2Fatom
```

If I just put the whole URL string as is, it works. However, since I have to get them as two parts and construct them, I would like to see how to make it work

If I have it like below, it works.

```
String url = "http://alfresco-test:8180/alfesco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom";
```

If I do the following, it does not work.

```
String host="http://alfresco-test:8180";
String cmisEndpoint = "alfesco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom";
String url = host + "/" + emisEndpoint;
```

Similarly, the following does not work as well

```
String host="http://alfresco-test:8180";
String cmisEndpoint = "alfesco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom";
String url = URLEncoder.encode( (host + "/" + emisEndpoint), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I apologize that, I did not notice a typo in there. In the configuration xml piece, for the property cmis-endpoint, I had **alfesco** instead of **alfresco**. 
My eyes are failing me I guess.

Then I used the following that works.

```
java.net.URL cmisUrl = new URL ((this.host + this.cmisAccessPoint));
cmisAtomPubUrl = cmisUrl.toString();
```